# Writing to an Object within a Loop

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create an object with the following function's output.

```js
var threads = {
 "thread1": {
  "upvotes": {
   "8fsygfs": true,
   "atw9g87": true,
   "atw923swg87": true,
   "34j2njk": true
  },
  "downvotes": {
   "jne280n": true,
   "892ned9": true,
   "28hd0ye": true,
   "cjsnd09": true,
   "02jd0d2": true,
  }
 },
 "thread2": {
  "upvotes": {
   "02jd0d2": true,
   "8fsygfs": true,
   "7dr4229": true,
   "232c3f25": true,
   "34j2njk": true,
   "atw9g87": true,
   "atw923swg87": true,
  },
  "downvotes": {
   "jne280n": true,
   "9ah8229": true,
   "89h208d": true,
   "28hd0ye": true,
   "cjsnd09": true
  }
 },
 "thread3": {
  "upvotes": {
   "02jd0d2": true,
   "9ah8229": true,
   "838w32l": true,
   "78awg2l": true,
   "34j2njk": true
  },
  "downvotes": {
   "jne280n": true,
   "atw9g87": true,
   "892ned9": true,
   "28hd0ye": true
  }
 }
}

var members = [
 "8fsygfs",
 "atw9g87",
 "atw923swg87",
 "34j2njk",
 "jne280n",
 "892ned9",
 "28hd0ye",
 "cjsnd09",
 "02jd0d2",
 "9ah8229",
 "9ah8229",
 "7dr4229",
 "232c3f25",
 "838w32l",
 "78awg2l"
]

function getAlignmentSets() {
    var checked = []
    members.forEach(k => {
     members.forEach(l => {
      var matches = 0
      if (k != l && (!checked.includes(l))) {
       Object.keys(threads).forEach(m => {
        var thread = Object.keys(threads[m].upvotes).concat(Object.keys(threads[m].downvotes))
        if (thread.includes(k) && thread.includes(l)) {
         matches++
        }
       })
       console.log(k + ": { " + l + ": " +  matches + " }" )
      }
     })
     checked.push(k)
    })
}

getAlignmentSets()
```

This function counts the total number of times two users voted on the same thread--regardless of whether they voted the same or differently. I need it to output an object that looks like this:

```js
"member1": {
    "member2": 2, // value is the number of times the this member has
    "member3": 1, // voted on the same thread as its parent
    ...
},
"member2": {
    "member3": 2,
    ...
},
...
```

I'm struggling with the concept of property bracket accessors in writing to an object within a loop, especially when writing children. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I've changed it to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your logic was correct, you're just not writing it to anything for returning. I assume this is what `coappearances` was for. You're missing this:

```
if(!coappearances[k])
    coappearances[k] = {};
coappearances[k][l] = matches;
```

Example below:

```js
var threads = {
 "thread1": {
  "upvotes": {
   "8fsygfs": true,
   "atw9g87": true,
   "atw923swg87": true,
   "34j2njk": true
  },
  "downvotes": {
   "jne280n": true,
   "892ned9": true,
   "28hd0ye": true,
   "cjsnd09": true,
   "02jd0d2": true,
  }
 },
 "thread2": {
  "upvotes": {
   "02jd0d2": true,
   "8fsygfs": true,
   "7dr4229": true,
   "232c3f25": true,
   "34j2njk": true,
   "atw9g87": true,
   "atw923swg87": true,
  },
  "downvotes": {
   "jne280n": true,
   "9ah8229": true,
   "89h208d": true,
   "28hd0ye": true,
   "cjsnd09": true
  }
 },
 "thread3": {
  "upvotes": {
   "02jd0d2": true,
   "9ah8229": true,
   "838w32l": true,
   "78awg2l": true,
   "34j2njk": true
  },
  "downvotes": {
   "jne280n": true,
   "atw9g87": true,
   "892ned9": true,
   "28hd0ye": true
  }
 }
}

var members = [
 "8fsygfs",
 "atw9g87",
 "atw923swg87",
 "34j2njk",
 "jne280n",
 "892ned9",
 "28hd0ye",
 "cjsnd09",
 "02jd0d2",
 "9ah8229",
 "9ah8229",
 "7dr4229",
 "232c3f25",
 "838w32l",
 "78awg2l"
]

function getAlignmentSets() {
    var coappearances = {}
    var checked = []
    members.forEach(k => {
     members.forEach(l => {
      var matches = 0
      if (k != l && (!checked.includes(l))) {
       Object.keys(threads).forEach(m => {
        var thread = Object.keys(threads[m].upvotes).concat(Object.keys(threads[m].downvotes))
        if (thread.includes(k) && thread.includes(l)) {
         matches++
        }
       })
       //console.log(k + ": { " + l + ": " +  matches + " }" )
                if(!coappearances[k])
                   coappearances[k] = {};
                coappearances[k][l] = matches;
      }
     })
     checked.push(k)
    })
    return coappearances;
}

var result = getAlignmentSets();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This does what I needed, but it does reveal a flaw with my logic. I was trying to avoid checking pairs twice, but it seems to have caused an unintended issue. In any case, it's easily fixed. Thanks. Can you please express `coappearances[k][l]` without using bracket notation? This is strange to me because `coappearances[k]` is simply `"memberId"`, so `coappearances[k][l]` seems like it should either be `"memberId"[l]` or `"memberId"` (because it would simply take the name of the second accessor).

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but wanted to provide an alternate approach that is significantly more performant using `Set` containing the unique members in each thread:

```js
var threads = {
 "thread1": {
  "upvotes": {
   "8fsygfs": true,
   "atw9g87": true,
   "atw923swg87": true,
   "34j2njk": true
  },
  "downvotes": {
   "jne280n": true,
   "892ned9": true,
   "28hd0ye": true,
   "cjsnd09": true,
   "02jd0d2": true,
  }
 },
 "thread2": {
  "upvotes": {
   "02jd0d2": true,
   "8fsygfs": true,
   "7dr4229": true,
   "232c3f25": true,
   "34j2njk": true,
   "atw9g87": true,
   "atw923swg87": true,
  },
  "downvotes": {
   "jne280n": true,
   "9ah8229": true,
   "89h208d": true,
   "28hd0ye": true,
   "cjsnd09": true
  }
 },
 "thread3": {
  "upvotes": {
   "02jd0d2": true,
   "9ah8229": true,
   "838w32l": true,
   "78awg2l": true,
   "34j2njk": true
  },
  "downvotes": {
   "jne280n": true,
   "atw9g87": true,
   "892ned9": true,
   "28hd0ye": true
  }
 }
}

var members = [
 "8fsygfs",
 "atw9g87",
 "atw923swg87",
 "34j2njk",
 "jne280n",
 "892ned9",
 "28hd0ye",
 "cjsnd09",
 "02jd0d2",
 "9ah8229",
 "9ah8229",
 "7dr4229",
 "232c3f25",
 "838w32l",
 "78awg2l"
]

function getAlignmentSets() {
    // turn each thread into a Set of participating members
    const threadSets = Object.keys(threads).reduce((prev, thread) => {
      prev[thread] = new Set(
        [].concat(Object.keys(threads[thread].upvotes), Object.keys(threads[thread].downvotes))
      );
      return prev;
    }, {});

    // on each iteration, check if current user appears in each thread
    // reduce each additional member in the thread to a memberId => voteCount pair
    return members.reduce((memberData, curMember) => {
        memberData[curMember] = {};
        
        Object.keys(threadSets).forEach((set) => {
            const curThread = threadSets[set];
            if (curThread.has(curMember)) {
                Array.from(curThread.values()).reduce((p, userKey) => {
                    if (userKey === curMember) {
                        return p;
                    } else if (userKey in p) {
                        p[userKey] = p[userKey] + 1;
                    } else {
                        p[userKey] = 1;
                    }
                    return p;
                }, memberData[curMember]);
            }
        });
        return memberData;
    }, {});
}

console.log(getAlignmentSets());
```

You can check out the difference on JSPerf: https://jsperf.com/getalignmentset-versions/1

Comment: I'm going to keep the original answer because the question doesn't ask for an evaluation of the function itself, but this is very instructive. Thank you.

Comment: Definitely agree that the first answer is a better answer to your question and should be marked as such. No worries, hope it is helpful